# Is there a property that Html.ValidationSummary set?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to know if Html.ValidationSummary is present in code. The tag `div class="validation-summary-valid"` is not present in html if Html.ValidationSummary has a parameter of true. i.e. `Html.ValidationSummary(true)`, the result, there's no reliable way to know in jquery if Html.ValidationSummary is in code.

Is there a property that says so? The presence or absence of Html.ValidationSummary

**[EDIT: clarification]**

Putting Html.ValidationSummary with a parameter of true:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)   

    <b>Hello</b>
```

,and not putting any Html.ValidationSummary:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    <b>Hello</b>
```

,both code yields the same HTML(View Page Source):

```
    <b>Hello</b>
```

That being so, there's no <strike>reliable</strike> way from jQuery to know if Html.ValidationSummary is present or not in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because `ValidationSummary` helper does not return empty `<div class="validation-summary-errors"/>` if there is no errors (when `ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` returns `true`). In such case you need to have custom `ValidationSummary` which fixing that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString CustomValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper helper, string validationMessage = null)
        {

            StringBuilder summary = new StringBuilder();

            summary.Append("<div class=\"validation-summary-errors\">");

            if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                summary.Append("</div>");

                return new MvcHtmlString(summary.ToString());
            }

            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage))
            {
                summary.Append("<ul>");
                summary.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", validationMessage);

                summary.Append("</ul>");
                summary.Append("</div>");

                return new MvcHtmlString(summary.ToString());
            }


            summary.Append("<ul>");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> state in helper.ViewData.ModelState)
            {
                foreach (ModelError error in state.Value.Errors)
                {
                    summary.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(error.ErrorMessage));
                }

            }

            summary.Append("</ul>");
            summary.Append("</div>");

            return new MvcHtmlString(summary.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This custom `ValidationSummary` helper will generate empty `validation-summary-errors div` even if there is was no errors, other words `<div class="validation-summary-errors"/>` would be present in your html every time, like you want.

Comment: From what I gleaned from ASP.NET MVC source code, it doesn't set any property to indicate the code has ValidationSummary. The boon of having the source :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just talking about jQuery, can you not just do:

```
if ($('.validation-summary-valid').size() > 0)
{
  // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Cannot do that, there's nothing to test. The tag is not present in html if Html.ValidationSummary has a parameter of `true`. What's weird, only when there's an error(using `Html.ValidationSummary(true)` after submitting(sans jQuery), that's the only time the tag gets created

Comment: .size() returns 0 if there are no html elements matching that class. Perhaps, I'm not understanding your question